Error setting speech sensitvity for NAO's ASR engine
I want to set the sensitivity of the ASR engine to be able to be at its maximum power to detect the ambient speech, I do this:
 self.speech_detection = ALProxy("ALSpeechRecognition", "10.0.0.56", 9559)
 self.speech_detection.setParameter("Sensibility", 0.9)

But I get the following error:
RuntimeError:   ALSpeechRecognition::setParameter
        AsrHybridNuance::xSetParameter
    You need to stop or pause the ASR engine to be able to make this call.

Any clues?
